# Circuitpython | Traceback ValueError | >BUTTON_A is being used<

Tags: python, valueerror, traceback, adafruit-circuitpython, mu

### Context

I hope I can get some help. Thanks in advance

I recently acquired a Circuit Playground Express as a project for college, and I am having some issues programming with it, specially because the Traceback is constantly giving me an error which I don't know how to fix, and I have tried several things now, and couldn't get anything different.

I am using a IDE for CircuitPython called "Mu Editor" https://codewith.mu/en/download, which provides me some interesting tools that have made my work kind of easier. (I have to clarify I have never coded in Python, so I am kinda lost in everything)

### Error

```
Traceback (ultima llamada reciente):
Archivo "code.py", línea 61, en <module>
ValueError: BUTTON_A está siendo utilizado

El código terminó de ejecutar.
```

---

### Code which is getting error

I am having the issue specially on these pieces of code:

- **Variable a_but**, which will allow me to use the BUTTON_A of the Circuit Playground, so it does something when it is pressed

```
a_but = DigitalInOut(board.D4)
a_but.direction = Direction.INPUT
a_but.pull = Pull.DOWN
```

- **Variable b_but**, which will allow me to use the BUTTON_B of the Circuit Playground, so it does something when it is pressed

```
b_but = DigitalInOut(board.D5)
b_but.direction = Direction.INPUT
b_but.pull = Pull.DOWN
```

- **Variable pixels** that will allow me to access to modify the neopixels of the Circuit Playground

```
pixels = neopixel.NeoPixel(board.NEOPIXEL, 10, brightness=1.0)
```

---

***Examples of the above variables when being used:***

- **a_but and b_but**

```
while True:
     if a_but.value:
        print("Button A pressed")

     if b_but.value:
        print("Button B pressed")
```

- **pixels**

```
if temp < 36:
   pixels[0] = (0, 0, 255)
   pixels[1] = (0, 0, 255)
   pixels[2] = (0, 0, 255)

elif temp >= 36 and temp <= 37.2:
     pixels[3] = (0, 0, 255)
     pixels[4] = (0, 0, 255)
     pixels[5] = (0, 0, 255)
     pixels[6] = (0, 0, 255)

else:
     pixels[7] = (0, 0, 255)
     pixels[8] = (0, 0, 255)
     pixels[9] = (0, 0, 255)
```

---

Here is the complete code in case you want to take a look (It might have some errors since that error is blocking me from moving on):

```
import time
import analogio
import board
import neopixel
import pulseio
import digitalio
from digitalio import DigitalInOut, Direction, Pull
import adafruit_irremote

import adafruit_thermistor
from adafruit_circuitplayground import cp


def sign(value):
    if value > 0:
        return 1
    if value < 0:
        return -1
    return 0


def pulse_test():
    # Turn only pixel #1 green
    pixels[1] = (0, 255, 0)

    # How many light readings per sample
    NUM_OVERSAMPLE = 10
    # How many samples we take to calculate 'average'
    NUM_SAMPLES = 20
    samples = [0] * NUM_SAMPLES

    i = True
    while i:
        for i in range(NUM_SAMPLES):
            # Take NUM_OVERSAMPLE number of readings really fast
            oversample = 0
            for s in range(NUM_OVERSAMPLE):
                oversample += float(light.value)
            # and save the aver age from the oversamples
            samples[i] = oversample / NUM_OVERSAMPLE  # Find the average

            mean = sum(samples) / float(len(samples))  # take the average
            print((samples[i] - mean,))  # 'center' the reading

            if i > 0:
                # If the sign of the data has changed munus to plus
                # we have one full waveform (2 zero crossings), pulse LED
                if sign(samples[i] - mean) <= 0 and sign(samples[i - 1] - mean) > 0:
                    pixels[9] = (200, 0, 0)  # Pulse LED
                else:
                    pixels[9] = (0, 0, 0)  # Turn LED off

            time.sleep(0.025)  # change to go faster/slower

        if b_but.value:
            i = False

    pixels[1] = (0, 0, 0)
    pixels[9] = (0, 0, 0)

a_but = DigitalInOut(board.D4)
a_but.direction = Direction.INPUT
a_but.pull = Pull.DOWN

b_but = DigitalInOut(board.D5)
b_but.direction = Direction.INPUT
b_but.pull = Pull.DOWN

pixels = neopixel.NeoPixel(board.NEOPIXEL, 10, brightness=1.0)
light = analogio.AnalogIn(board.LIGHT)

RED = (255, 0, 0)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
CYAN = (0, 255, 255)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
PURPLE = (180, 0, 255)
PIXELS_OFF = (0, 0, 0)

pulsein = pulseio.PulseIn(board.IR_RX, maxlen=120, idle_state=True)
decoder = adafruit_irremote.GenericDecode()

while True:

    pulse = decoder.read_pulses(pulsein)
    try:
        received_code = decoder.decode_bits(pulse)
        print("\n\nSeñal Adquirida : ", received_code)

        if received_code == (223, 32, 111, 144):
            print("¡Sospecha de infeccion detectada!\n\n")
            for i in range(3):
                pixels.fill(YELLOW)
                pixels.show()
                time.sleep(0.05)

                pixels.fill(PIXELS_OFF)
                pixels.show()
                time.sleep(0.05)

            print("¿Desea realizar un testeo basico?:")
            print("\n\n Si. Presione A\n No. Presione B")
            pixels[0] = (0, 255, 0)
            pixels[1] = (0, 255, 0)
            pixels[2] = (0, 255, 0)
            pixels[3] = (0, 255, 0)
            pixels[4] = (0, 255, 0)
            pixels[5] = (255, 0, 0)
            pixels[6] = (255, 0, 0)
            pixels[7] = (255, 0, 0)
            pixels[8] = (255, 0, 0)
            pixels[9] = (255, 0, 0)

            while True:
                if a_but.value:
                    testeo_respuesta = True
                    for x in range(2):
                        pixels.fill(PIXELS_OFF)
                        pixels.show()
                        for i in range(9):
                            pixels[10] = (0, 255, 0)
                            time.sleep(0.075)
                    break

                if b_but.value:
                    testeo_respuesta = False
                    for x in range(2):
                        pixels.fill(PIXELS_OFF)
                        pixels.show()
                        for i in range(9):
                            pixels[i] = (255, 0, 0)
                            time.sleep(0.075)
                    break
                time.sleep(0.075)

            pixels.fill(PIXELS_OFF)
            pixels.show()

            if testeo_respuesta:

                for test_num in range(19):
                    regTemp = [cp.temperature] * test_num
                    time.sleep(1.0)
                for k in range(19):
                    pixels[0] = (0, 0, 255)
                    temp = 0
                    if temp < regTemp[k]:
                        temp = regTemp[k]
                    pixels[0] = (0, 0, 0)
                    time.sleep(0.5)

                if temp < 36:
                    pixels[0] = (0, 0, 255)
                    pixels[1] = (0, 0, 255)
                    pixels[2] = (0, 0, 255)
                    pixels[3] = (0, 0, 0)
                    pixels[4] = (0, 0, 0)
                    pixels[5] = (0, 0, 0)
                    pixels[6] = (0, 0, 0)
                    pixels[7] = (0, 0, 0)
                    pixels[8] = (0, 0, 0)
                    pixels[9] = (0, 0, 0)
                    resultado = True
                elif temp >= 36 and temp <= 37.2:
                    pixels[0] = (0, 0, 0)
                    pixels[1] = (0, 0, 0)
                    pixels[2] = (0, 0, 0)
                    pixels[3] = (0, 0, 255)
                    pixels[4] = (0, 0, 255)
                    pixels[5] = (0, 0, 255)
                    pixels[6] = (0, 0, 255)
                    pixels[7] = (0, 0, 0)
                    pixels[8] = (0, 0, 0)
                    pixels[9] = (0, 0, 0)
                    resultado = False
                else:
                    pixels[0] = (0, 0, 0)
                    pixels[1] = (0, 0, 0)
                    pixels[2] = (0, 0, 0)
                    pixels[3] = (0, 0, 0)
                    pixels[4] = (0, 0, 0)
                    pixels[5] = (0, 0, 0)
                    pixels[6] = (0, 0, 0)
                    pixels[7] = (0, 0, 255)
                    pixels[8] = (0, 0, 255)
                    pixels[9] = (0, 0, 255)
                    resultado = True
        else:
            print("¡No hay riesgo detectado!")
            for i in range(3):
                pixels.fill(GREEN)
                pixels.show()

                time.sleep(0.05)

                pixels.fill(PIXELS_OFF)
                pixels.show()

                time.sleep(0.05)
    except:
        continue

    time.sleep(0.025)
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please don't post *images* of text. Just put the text of your error message in the question, formatted as a code sample.